# How to copy a recordset from one table and add to another table?

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have two tables and I have a form linking to one of them. I want to check a value and if it is true, add the record the other table by using VBA.
Can anyone help me, please?

This is my code, but it does not work:

```
Dim rec1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rec2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rec1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TotalTPAq")
Set rec2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Visi")

rec1.MoveFirst
Do Until rec1.EOF

    If rec1!Date = PlanDate.Value Then ' planDate is a text box
        rec2.AddNew
        rec2![Planing Date History] = PlanDate.Value
        rec2.Update
        rec2.Close
    End If
    rec1.MoveNext
Loop
rec1.Close

Set rec2 = Nothing
Set rec1 = Nothing

DoCmd.Close
```

Comment: i am beginner in access and vba, it dose not get any error message just it stops at the row rec2.addnew ,i do not know what is the problem! i changed the place of rec2.close but the result is the same!

Comment: i just tested it in access i placed rec2.close after rec1.close but the result was the same.

Comment: in fact i have a form that linked to a query. i use checkbox for selecting the records in the form that i want to add the planDate.value to the table of the query for the selected records. in fact i want to have another table to add those selected records to it to have a history of what is happened because the value of the tables of the query changes.

Answer (score 3):

This should provide a start for you:

```
'Run query to fill table
Private Sub btnRnQry_Click()

    'No value entered
    If IsNull(Me.txtEntry) Or Me.txtEntry = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Is null or empty")
    Else
        'Assign value to variable
        Dim entry As String
        entry = Me.txtEntry

        Dim sql As String
        sql = "INSERT INTO tableTwo ([First Name],Surname,[Phone Number] )" & _
              "SELECT * " & _
              "FROM tableOne " & _
              "WHERE [First Name] = '" & entry & "';"

        'Run the SQL
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql

    End If

End Sub
```